# upgrade no longer appears

Tags: linux

My updates reminder used to suggest upgrade to Ulyana from Tricia, but no longer does so.  I think I've switched something off.  Can I get it to revert to offering,Which looked a lot easier) or do I have to upgrade from the internet now?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to the Application Menu -> "Administration" -> "Update Manager", and use the update using that. [Here is an article](https://www.techsolveprac.com/upgrade-linux-mint/) that will give you a step-by-step run-through of what to do. Specifically at step 3. If that is confusing to you, see the video at the end of the article that will show you.

Comment: My menu bears no resemblance to the one in the video (or the one I had with Mint Tessa, if it comes to that)  typing in 'system info' brings up nothing but a list of things to download.  Quite a few things have not been where they should since I bought this.  It's extremely frustrating.  Makes me want to bang my head against a wall. It's a purpose built linux laptop.  There's also nothing in the edit menu of the update manager that helps.

Comment: What happens when you try to launch "Update Manager" from the menu?

Comment: first off just have system up to date.  Edit brings up drop down menu with preferenences, system snapshots and software sources

Comment: It does not bring up the Welcome to the Update Manager screen seen in the video

Comment: I got the Welcome screen up but it made no difference. I've been through the video step by step, but the option to upgrade simply doesn't appear.